Power BI dataflow using direct query
Using GCC
I am creating a dataflow (Gen1) and want it to run in Direct Query mode rather than uploading 400GB to Power BI on a refresh schedule.  Following instructions from Microsoft (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/transform-model/dataflows/dataflows-directquery) I see that I must:

Navigate to the Premium dataflow, and set enhanced compute engine to On.
Refresh the dataflow.

It seems odd that "Refresh the dataflow" is part of the process to not refresh the dataflow, but... OK.
So, I clicked Refresh 53 minutes ago and it's still refreshing.  I can't seem to get any data to appear in a Power BI report.  Do I need to wait until the refresh has completed?
Also, creating a Power BI report (using Power BI Desktop) I'm expecting to see an option to use Direct query mode:
"...connecting to a dataflow by using the Dataflows connector prompts you to choose whether to connect to tables through DirectQuery or Import."
...but I don't.
Again, do I need to wait for the refresh to complete?
How long should it take for the refresh to complete when it is allegedly configured to use Direct Query mode (i.e. not refresh)?

Yes.  You must wait until after the refresh has completed.
After 64 minutes the dataflow had processed 106 million rows.  (so, now it's using storage capacity that the broken Fabric Metrics capacity app won't show me?)  Once that was completed, I could create a new Power BI report using the dataflow.  When I select the tables and click Load, I can select Import or Direct query.  If I select the tables and Transform Data, once I select Close and Apply and wait for a bit for Power BI to process who knows what, I can select Import or Direct Query for each table.  At this point, Power BI has not produced anything to help me make that choice, so I don't know what value it thought it was adding during the delay.
As for the report I created from the dataflow before I followed the instructions in the question:  I don't see any way to choose Import or Direct Query and when I click Refresh I see it wants to load data (so it's in Import mode).  So that's a complete do-over.
Overall, my Power BI journey has been less than pleasant so far.  But that's OK.  I'm sure the product will get a complete overhaul soon (like it has every month) so the problems I'm having today will be replaced by completely different problems.
